# How can pd.get_dummies() be used to dummy-code a list of categories?

Tags: python

I understand that `pd.get_dummies()` works very well for creating a dummy set to represent a categorical variable (in my case for a decision tree algorithm). My question is, how can this be adapted to handle entries that are a list of categories?

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({
   'id': ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], 
   'category': [['a', 'b'], 'b', 'c', ['b', 'c']],
   'x': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
   'y': [10, 20, 30, 40]
})

...

a_dummied

  id a  b  c  x  y
0 i  1  1  0  p 10
1 j  0  1  0  q 20
2 k  0  0  1  r 30
3 l  0  1  1  s 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode the `category` column and then call `pd.get_dummies`:

```
print( pd.get_dummies(a.explode('category').set_index('id'), prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(level=0).sum() )
```

Prints:

```
    a  b  c
id         
i   1  1  0
j   0  1  0
k   0  0  1
l   0  1  1
```

---

EDIT: To work with more columns, first make a `pd.get_dummies()` on `category` column and then `.join` with original dataframe:

```
c = pd.get_dummies( a[['id', 'category']].explode('category').set_index('id'), prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(level=0).sum()
print( a.set_index('id').drop(columns='category').join(c) )
```

Prints:

```
    x   y  a  b  c
id                
i   p  10  1  1  0
j   q  20  0  1  0
k   r  30  0  0  1
l   s  40  0  1  1
```

Comment: This works, but I realized after asking that my MWE isn't sufficiently specific. I have additional columns that need to be preserved. MWE is updated to reflect this. Can your answer be adapted?